# Running script with HERE_DOC method in background

Tags: bash, background, heredoc

I have a script that should be run in background. I must answer a question as soon as I run the bash..How can I do that?

```
(nohup python script.py lst '<<HERE yes HERE' &)
```

Comment: If you just need a single line of input, `echo yes | nohup python gpvul.py lst &` is simpler. The parentheses are unnecessary even with your current code.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `<<` heredoc is multiline, like

```
somescript <<EOF &
input
EOF
```

the heredoc delimiter should be alone on the final line

You can use one line heredoc with `<<<`, like:

```
somescript <<<"this coming from stdin" &
```

Comment: Technically `<<<` is a "here string". It's a Bash extension, so not POSIX portable.