# How to launch multiple command lines in parallel

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm currently launching a shell file on Gromacs (Linux) with 60 different commands in it. When launching the file the commands are processed sequentially one by one.

I want to launch all of them in parallel and in background.
How can I achieve that?

Here some lines of my shell file:

```
gmx rms -s md.tpr -n index_analysis.ndx -f md.xtc -o rmsd_fc_chain_B.xvg -tu ns << eof
29
29
eof

gmx rms -s md.tpr -n index_analysis.ndx -f md.xtc -o rmsd_fc_chain_C.xvg -tu ns << 
eof
32
32
eof

gmx rms -s md.tpr -n index_analysis.ndx -f md.xtc -o rmsd_fc_chain_D.xvg -tu ns << 
eof
35
35
eof
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wanted to have the full benefit of a tool explicitly written for this type of thing, you could use **GNU Parallel**. You would probably change your shell script (let's call it `commands`) to look like this:

```
printf "29\n29\n" | gmx rms -s md.tpr -n index_analysis.ndx -f md.xtc -o rmsd_fc_chain_B.xvg -tu ns
printf "32\n32\n" | gmx rms -s md.tpr -n index_analysis.ndx -f md.xtc -o rmsd_fc_chain_C.xvg -tu ns
```

Then you could run:

```
parallel -j 8 < commands
```

if you wanted to run 8 at a time, or `-j 32` if you wanted to run 32 at a time. You can test what it would do, without actually doing anything, by using `--dry-run`:

```
parallel --dry-run < cmds
printf "29\n29\n" | gmx rms -s md.tpr -n index_analysis.ndx -f md.xtc -o rmsd_fc_chain_B.xvg -tu ns
printf "32\n32\n" | gmx rms -s md.tpr -n index_analysis.ndx -f md.xtc -o rmsd_fc_chain_C.xvg -tu ns
```

You can also get an `Estimated Time of Arrival` with `--eta`, and also spread the jobs over any other computers on your network that you can `ssh` into. You get the idea - very flexible.

Answer (score 1):

run them in the background using `&`, e.g.

```
sleep 60 &
sleep 60 &
sleep 60 &
```

will run 3 times sleep in background (and they are executed in parallel). See e.g. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-line-run-in-background/ or [executing shell command in background from script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683910/executing-shell-command-in-background-from-script)

For the combination in use with the here_doc : [Running script with HERE_DOC method in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337304/runing-script-with-here-doc-method-in-background) . This should work (only one command shown):

```
gmx rms -s md.tpr -n index_analysis.ndx -f md.xtc -o rmsd_fc_chain_B.xvg -tu ns << eof &
29
29
eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the command you have written you might want to run something like (test all A..Z with all 1..100):

```
gmx rms -s md.tpr -n index_analysis.ndx -f md.xtc -o rmsd_fc_chain_{A..Z}.xvg -tu ns << 
eof
{1..100}
eof
```

Using GNU Parallel you would do this:

```
doit() {
  printf "$2\n$2\n" |
  gmx rms -s md.tpr -n index_analysis.ndx -f md.xtc -o rmsd_fc_chain_${1}.xvg -tu ns
}
export -f doit
parallel doit ::: {A..Z} ::: {1..100}
```

Learn more about GNU Parallel by walking through the tutorial: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html